# ggplot: remove NA factor level in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I omit the `NA` level of a factor from a legend?

[image: Pesky NA legend value.....]

From the `nycflights13` database, I created a new continuous variable called `tot_delay`, and then created a factor called `delay_class` with 4 levels. When I plot, I filter out `NA` values, but they still appear in the legend. Here's my code:

```
library(nycflights13); library(ggplot2)

flights$tot_delay = flights$dep_delay + flights$arr_delay
flights$delay_class <- cut(flights$tot_delay,                                   
                           c(min(flights$tot_delay, na.rm = TRUE), 0, 20 , 120,
                             max(flights$tot_delay, na.rm = TRUE)),   
                           labels = c("none", "short","medium","long"))     

filter(flights, !is.na(tot_delay)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = carrier, fill = delay_class), position = "fill")
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have one data point where `delay_class` is `NA`, but `tot_delay` isn't. This point is not being caught by your filter. Changing your code to:

```
filter(flights, !is.na(delay_class)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = carrier, fill = delay_class), position = "fill")
```

does the trick:

[image]

Alternatively, if you absolutely must have that extra point, you can override the `fill` legend as follows:

```
filter(flights, !is.na(tot_delay)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = carrier, fill = delay_class), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual( breaks = c("none","short","medium","long"),
                    values = scales::hue_pal()(4) )
```

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in @gatsky's answer, all discrete scales also include the `na.translate` argument. The feature actually existed since [ggplot 2.2.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.2.0); I just wasn't aware of it at the time I posted my answer. For completeness, its usage in the original question would look like

```
filter(flights, !is.na(tot_delay)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = carrier, fill = delay_class), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.translate=FALSE)
```

Comment: Ah! So simple. I should have filtered by delay_class to begin with. Since there was one extra point, it was difficult to see that NA on the graph itself, although it showed on the legend. You have my vote for the ```scale_fill_manual()``` method of overwriting a legend.

Answer (score 70):

The parent example isn't a good illustration of the problem (of course unexpected `NA` values should be tracked down and eliminated), but this is the top result on Google so it should be noted that there is a now an option in `scale_XXX_XXX`  to prevent NA levels from displaying in the legend by setting `na.translate = F`. For example:

```
# default    
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1,2,NA), y = c(1,1,NA), a = c("A","B",NA)),
           aes(x, y, colour = a)) + geom_point(size = 4)
```

[image]

```
# with na.translate = F    
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1,2,NA), y = c(1,1,NA), a = c("A","B",NA)),
           aes(x, y, colour = a)) + geom_point(size = 4) + 
           scale_colour_discrete(na.translate = F)
```

[image]

This works in ggplot2 3.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `scale_color_manual` or `scale_fill_manual` when knowing that the color of `NA` is `grey50`. So you could specify the `values` and only the `breaks` for the ones you want to plot. Here is some reproducible code (data @gatsky):

```r
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,NA), y = c(1,1,NA), a = c("A","B",NA))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, colour = a)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "grey50"),
                     breaks = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]

As you can see by specifying all the colors in `values` and only the `breaks` for A and B will remove the NA from the legend.

---

If you want to have the standard colors in your legend, you could use the `hue_pal` function from the `scales` package like this:

```r
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,NA), y = c(1,1,NA), a = c("A","B",NA))
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, colour = a)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(hue_pal()(2), "grey50"),
                     breaks = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]

---

And finally using the data from the OP with an `scale_fill_manual` example like this:

```r
library(nycflights13) 
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

filter(flights, !is.na(tot_delay)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = carrier, fill = delay_class), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(hue_pal()(4), "grey50"),
                    breaks = c("none", "short", 'medium', 'long'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I like @Artem's method above, i.e., getting to the bottom of why there are NA's in your df. However, sometimes you *know* there are NA's, and you just want to exclude them. In that case, simply using 'na.omit' should work:

```
na.omit(flights) %>% ggplot() +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = carrier, fill = delay_class), position = "fill")
```

Comment: The problem with this, is that it removes all rows with NA values in any column, not just the column I'm filling with ggplot. This may lead to some observations filtered out that one would want to keep in.

Comment: @RichPauloo -- you question, quoted from above, was "How can I easily omit NA values from the legend?" If you had difficulty (for whatever reason) finding which variable or variables it was that was giving you the problem, then using 'na.omit' would be expedient. However, I **always** encourage people to figure out why they have NA's, as mentioned in my reply. So, here is a question for you (since I checked *my* code before posting). What is the difference in the file / cases / rows in the flights file if you use 'na.omit(flights)' vs. 'filter(flights, !is.na(tot_delay))' ?

Comment: The difference is that if you'd use different dataset, you could unexpectedly lose data using na.omit(). The dplyr approach is more robust.