# plot geom_point on top of geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe:

```
test <- structure(list(Sample_ID = c("S1","S2", "S3", "S4", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"), 
                       CN_Region = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                       MedianLog2Ratio = c(-0.2, -0.2, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.2, -0.1, -0.3), 
             CN_truth = c("2", "2", "2", NA, "2", "2", "2", "1")), class = c("data.table","data.frame"))
```

When I plot `hist` it works fine:
hist(test$MedianLog2Ratio)

I would like to plot a per region histogram using ggplot and overlay with `geom_points` `CN_truth` associated with the `SampleID`:

```
g <- ggplot(test, aes(x = MedianLog2Ratio)) + geom_histogram()
g + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(CN_truth))
```

Plot should look like this loosely (of course it will have fewer bins with lesser data):
[image: sample_plot]                                                      where legend refers to `CN_truth` and title is `CN_Region`

Comment: What's the `y` of your `geom_point`?

Comment: Y = 0, would just like to plot it at 0/1 frequency

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is as below:

```
test <- data.frame(Sample_ID = c("S1","S2", "S3", "S4", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"), 
                       CN_Region = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                       MedianLog2Ratio = c(-0.2, -0.2, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.2, -0.1, -0.3), 
                       CN_truth = c("2", "2", "2", NA, "2", "2", "2", "1"))
test <- transform(test, freqmlr = ave(seq(nrow(test)), MedianLog2Ratio, FUN=length))



g <- ggplot(test, aes(x = MedianLog2Ratio)) + geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white")+
     geom_point(aes(x=MedianLog2Ratio, y=freqmlr, colour=factor(CN_truth)))+
        xlab('MedianLog2Ratio') +
        ylab('Freq')+
        labs(colour='CN_truth')
g
```

[image]

There are many posts for you **if** you wanted to remove `NA` from the legend (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493163/ggplot-remove-na-factor-level-in-legend/45493345) one). Please also note that if there are many points with the same value for x-axis you can move them a bit within each histogram to make them visible. For instance by adding random decimal value:

```
g <- ggplot(test, aes(x = MedianLog2Ratio)) + geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white")+
  geom_point(aes(x=(MedianLog2Ratio+runif(nrow(test), 0.0, 0.010)), y=freqmlr, 
                 colour=CN_truth ))+
  xlab('MedianLog2Ratio') +
  ylab('Freq')+
  labs(colour='CN_truth')
g  + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), limits = c("1", "2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to not plot NAs? Also I would like to make a separate plot per region. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Please see above, the second part of my answer to your question.

Comment: Hi, I don't want just want to exclude NA just from the legend. I don't want to plot geom_points for NAs at all.So far I have: ` test$temp <- 0.3                                 
pdf("myplot.pdf", onefile = T)
for var in unique(test$CN_Region){
g <- ggplot(test, aes(x = MedianLog2Ratio)) + geom_histogram(color="black", fill="white")+
  geom_point(aes(x=(MedianLog2Ratio+runif(nrow(test), 0.0, 0.010)), y=temp, 
                 colour=CN_truth ))+
  xlab('MedianLog2Ratio') +
  ylab('Freq')+
  labs(colour='CN_truth')
print(g)
}`But this is plotting NA's on the plot.How can I remove them?

Comment: Firstly, you must be very specific the first time you post your question. Adding revisions in the comments is not really the right way. Secondly, this is **not** plotting `NA` values on the plot at all. If you pay enough attention there is a warning at the end that says *Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).* Finally, keep in mind that the frequency of that row before being removed for the plot is still counted. If you want to remove NA rows before calculating frequencies (which I guess you should not) you can exclude NA rows early, in the beginning, using `na.omit(test)`.